# Receive text and picture from server in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to refresh an img tag every second. so I wrote a little bit of code that changes src attribute of img tag and it loads the picture from image.php.
All good.
Sometimes the image.php doesn't have a picture, or sth went wrong in image.php. I need image.php to send a message along with the picture to determine validity of the picture, or tell me the error number.
so I need a php code that puts a text and a picture in it's output.

Right now I use

```
//code
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

and image.php acts like a .jpg file and I can use it in src attribute of img tag. But I need a way to find out if image.php is outputing a valid image and not a php error.

js code:

```
var newImage = new Image();
var count = 0;
function updateImage()
{

    if(newImage.complete) {
    document.getElementById("myimg").src = newImage.src;
    newImage = new Image();
    newImage.src = "socket.php?message=0&image" + count++ + ".jpg";
    }

}
```

Comment: What means "picture is not valid"?

Comment: "picture is not valid" means that image.php failed and the image that it created is not a real image. I'm using this image in src attribute so if the output of image.php is not an image but an error, the img tag will try to show that message as an image and that will fail and the img tag will show nothing.

Comment: "Detecting if it is an image" is theme for AI research. You can handle if you got SERVER error (404, 500 etc), for example. Show your java script.

Comment: added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First method:

Using `onerror` property of the `img` element:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="alert('The image could not be loaded.')">
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onerror.asp)

You can use function as value of `onerror` property and use this function in java script. Example is below.

HTML:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="handleError();">
```

JS:

```
function handleError() {
    // do something
}
```

Another way is to set `onerror` handler to instance of Image class:

```
var image = new Image();
img.src = /* url to the imgage */;
image.onload = function() {
    // assign img.src to to src property of the `img` element
}
image.onerror = function() {
    // do actions on error
}
```

Note:
2nd way is the way how to use `new Image()` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript-wise, you can find out about image failing to load via `error` event ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/646GP/)).

Perhaps, you could request the same URL via Ajax if the image fails to load, to obtain the error message. Unless you'd want to encode error messages as images too (and decode them client-side), of course, which may, or may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Ajax for such a task, and send back the image path and any other added information from the server.

The Ajax response can be easily read by the client.

Comment: I don't want to save the image on the server. The image.php acts like an image. so there is no "image path", just an image or a message error.

Comment: @user3604987 You ask to do something instead of helping you. Show what you did and we will help you.